# SQL Server Management Studio 2012, authentic multi-user login

Tags: sql-server

Issue:

I set up SQL Server and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio on the Administration login.

When I login on my login I can open SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, however I cannot access the database. I can see the database name but I am not able to open it.

Error message:

> The database xyz is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create your user and assign it to login for accessing the database.

Assuming you want to have read/write access:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\User_name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [Database_name]
GO
CREATE USER [Domain\User_name] FOR LOGIN [Domain\User_name]
GO
USE [Database_name]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'Domain\User_name'
GO
USE [Database_name]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'Domain\User_name'
GO
```

Comment: I actually have used EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Domain\User_name'
GO as I wanted a full control for it. But the above got me to it.